# Exit and Return in Proc TCL

Tags: return, tcl, exit, proc

I want to know the difference between Exit and Return inside a proc.
I have a script that contains a lot of proc, one of them uses exit and some value ex:

```
proc someProc {code} {
    exit $code
}
```

and another one is like:

```
proc multiply {value} {
    set number [expr {$value * 5}]
    return $number
}
```

Does the exit stop the running script or what is the difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `exit` command makes the current **process** stop. The running program will be gone afterwards (though the file containing the code will still be there). Its optional argument is the error code to hand to the OS; the default is zero, for no-error-at-all.

The `return` command makes the current **procedure call** stop. The optional argument provides a way to say what the result of the call to the procedure is; the default is the empty string (given that Tcl doesn't have `NULL`/`null`/`nil`/etc. at all).

Internally, `exit` does a system call to the “stop running this program” OS API, and `return` throws an exception that the general procedure management code transforms into the result of the call.

Comment: if i call multiply set a [multiply 5] the result will be 25, and if i call someProc will the script exit or just the proc will exit?

Comment: @virusivv If you call someProc, the entire script will exit, including any interactive shell you may be running.